# How can I Implement multiple uitableview in a single view?

Tags: iphone

Can anyone tell me how I can show multiple UITableViews in a single view?

Comment: if any one do not know then please don't reduce reputation. because I'm in such situation that I need to implement two uitableview in single view. may be my question is wrong but my need is correct.

Comment: you want both table views to see together or one at a time(one hidden and one visible)..?

Comment: two table view means ? did you mean same table view with different data or two different tables that appears together with different data ?

Comment: Hope this helps, but i haven't votedown you...

Comment: do one thing edit your question and explain your problem more openly, so that we can help you.

Comment: I means two different tableview with different data. Please help me. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

1) Draw different table views using different frames/ Drag and drop table views of different sizes, if using XiB.

2) Conform to table view protocols as usual and give implementation for delegate/datasource methods

3) In the delegate/datasource methods decide for which table view, it was called, using the table view's object. for example:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
    if(tableView == tableView1)
{
        //Do this
}
else if(tableView == tableView2)
{
        //Do that
}
}
```

Comment: Do this. This implies that you have "tableView1" and "tableView2" set up as ivars or perhaps as @properties. Having one set of delegate/data source methods that choose what data to respond with is going to keep you way saner than trying to build separate table management classes.

Answer (score 2):

To show multiple UITableView in a single view, you can Instantiate multiple UITableView and add them as subviews, like this:

```
UITableView *tb1 = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 100) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
UITableView *tb2 = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 100, 200, 100) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
UITableView *tb3 = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 200, 200, 100) style:UITableViewStylePlain];

[self.view addSubview:tb1];
[self.view addSubview:tb2];
[self.view addSubview:tb3];

[tb1 release];
[tb2 release];
[tb3 release];
```

Answer (score 1):

you will need to implement multiple tableView data source.
create new NSObject class for each table view:

in DataSourceOne.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


    @interface DataSourceOne : NSObject <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate> {
         NSMutableArray *data;
    }
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *data;

    - (id)initWithData:(NSMutableArray *)d;

    @end
```

Then, in every *.m files of data source classes implement source of each table view data.
Then, in ViewController class, which contains your table Views:

ViewController.h:

```
#import "DataSourceOne.h"
#import "DataSourceTwo.h"
#import "DataSourceThree.h"


@interface SearchView : UIViewController {
    DataSourceOne *ds1;
    DataSourceTwo *ds2;
    DataSourceThree *ds3; 
UITableView *table1;
UITableView *table2;
UITableView *table3;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView *table1;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView *table2;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView *table3;
@end
```

Finaly, set data sources and delegates to every UITableView:

```
ViewController.m:


    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
    ds1 = [[DataSourceOne alloc] init];
    [table1 setDataSource:ds1];   //for data source
    [table1 setDelegate:da1];     //for callbacks (didSekectRowAtIndexPath)
    ...
    }
```

You may even change gata source for every tableView at any time: just set new datasource and delegete to it. GL&HF